# Years worth of... Can it describe age?

Tags: idioms

I have recently stumbled upon the following sentences:

> Randomly found 115 years worth of change. Almost put it in the meter.

As seen [here](http://www.slightlywarped.com/crapfactory/curiosities/2013/january/images/4-History.jpg)

Does it mean he found an old coin or a lot of them?

Can `... years worth of...` describe age of an item?

Comment: No. Look at this example from the internet:'So, we are offering one reader the chance to win a year's worth of wash and blow drys at any Charles Worthington salon in the land.' [Note the apostrophe. I might put one in blow-dry's too.] 'N years' worth of X or X's' means 'the amount / total number of X or X's one might [expect to] use / need / accumulate' (or the amount etc of X that might accumulate) over N years.

Comment: So I thought, that's why I am confused as the example in my question suggests that the author refers to age of the item

Comment: How so? 'Almost put it in the meter' is a tragi-comic allusion to the soaring cost of energy (115 years' worth of change being taken loosely as 115 x 52 x $7.45 perhaps, if one counts one's loose change weekly).

Comment: To put things in a context please have a look here: http://www.slightlywarped.com/crapfactory/curiosities/2013/january/images/4-History.jpg It seems he found just one coin.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: [This](http://imgur.com/r/coins/FCEaq) is one source of the exact expression and it _does_ seem to refer to the age of a specific coin. I would expect "the meter" to be a simple parking meter, actually... That said, I would _never_ parse this expression as referring to age. It seems a similar mistake as thinking of a light year as a measure of time (or an ounce as a measure of volume, but that is a whole other can of worms...)

Comment: @strah: it would be more clear if you could add the reference to your question :) It is confusing indeed, because the expression is normally not used to indicate age.

Comment: @oerkelens: Ah, that's a non-standard (I'd say one-off) humorous application. Too subjective for the site, but doubtless what the OP is referring to. "Can ... 'years' worth of...' describe age of an item?" **In 99.999...% of cases, no**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually not, but here it's a coin. Since older coins are more valuable, he tries to measure their worth in years ;0

If I heard "10 years worth of change inside this sofa" I would say that's the amount of coins accumulated over 10 years.

I'm not sure if "115 years worth of change" is 100% correct usage; the phrase-coiner (go ahead, laugh at me!) is stretching the metaphor a bit here, but not to the point of breaking. A bit of poetic license, if you will.